# IndexError: tuple index out of range python postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

```
import psycopg2
import csv
#import operator
import pandas as pd
database = psycopg2.connect (database = "mydw", user="postgres",                         
password="1234", host="localhost", port="5432")
cursor = database.cursor()
a = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
print ("Read file")
c = pd.concat([a, b], join='outer')
c.to_csv("sorted_data.csv", index=False)
mydata = cursor.execute(delete)
cursor.execute("""Create Table Real.region
        (Country varchar(55),
        Capital varchar(55),
        State varchar(55),
        City varchar(55),
        Zip varchar(55)
         );""")

for row in c:
   cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Real.region (Country, Capital, State,         
    City, Zip)"""\
        """VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(row,))            
cursor.close()
database.commit()
database.close()
```

print("CSV data imported")

I am trying to merge 2 CSV files and put the resulted file in 
database. But I am facing the error ------

> File "C:/Users/Administrator/join-col.py", line 42, in 
>       """VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(row,))
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range

Please help

Comment: Try `len(row)` to know how many items in `row`.

Comment: What about `"""VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""", row)`, you're just passing a single value, otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If this

```
a = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
print ("Read file")
c = pd.concat([a, b], join='outer')
```

puts a list of tuples in c (you can verify that by printing it), then you should just need to change this

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Real.region (Country, Capital, State,         
City, Zip)"""\
    """VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",(row,))
```

to this

```
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Real.region (Country, Capital, State,         
City, Zip)"""\
    """VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)""",row)
```

The problem is that `row` is already a tuple. By doing `(row,)`, you are creating a tulpe with just **one element**, which is `row` itself.
This is also why you get an `IndexError`.